# Mimic Ajax requests with Superagent

Tags: node.js, express, supertest, superagent

I'm using Supertest (and thus Superagent) for some API testing on a Node.js project. I have a particular route that returns different content based on the type of request. Using expressJS's `req.xhr`, the code will return JSON if true or issue a redirect if false. I want to account for this in my tests but I'm struggling to get Superagent to mimic an XHR GET request.

According to ExpressJS documentation, it's looking for the `X-Requested-With` header in the request to be set to the value `XMLHttpRequest`. When I try to set this header using `.set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')` I get

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
```

Odd thing is, I can set other headers, even before this one, just fine
`.set('Accept', 'application/json')`. If the headers have already been written, this should fail too, but it doesn't. Also, checking `res.request.req._headers`, it appears nothing else is setting `X-Requested-With` so it's not like something else gave it a value either.

Comment: I'm not positive this will fix it, but is your `.set('Accept', 'application/json')` the last item, or are you trying to set the X-Requested-With header after you set the Accept header?

Comment: @Machtyn Thanks but I checked and it doesn't make a difference. I even commented out the `Accept` header altogether and the error is the same.